# Understanding Keras optimizer's get_updates (and tensor evaluation in general)

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras

I'm trying to make an optimizer that adapts its learning rate based on loss. After I started this approach, I realized how optimizers work, and that I should be making a learning rate scheduler instead.

Regardless, I'm interested to find out why my current approach isn't working, as I think it will help me finally come to grips with the difference between a symbolic tensor and an array.

In particular, the code runs and loss is decreasing, but

1. (fixed, due to an indentation issue, learning rate wasn't updating)
2. The print_tensor call doesn't seem to do anything, and neither does another K.print_tensor(counter,'C') inserted in the updates -- this makes it hard to debug. Currently the algorithm seems quite unstable and hard to debug without output.

   - Just using a callback to print stuff now
3. I'm not sure returning [0.0,0.0,0.0] in the switch statement is the preferred way to handle a if X do Y (else do nothing) situation. Also it seems K.switch evaluates both sides regardless of the condition

   - Fixed using something like K.update(a, K.switch(bool, a, 0))
4. The output makes little sense, things don't seem to update as expected.

   - Is the evaluation order of the returned list not guaranteed? If so, how can I make it so.

```py
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras import callbacks, optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.legacy import interfaces


class AutoOptim(optimizers.Nadam):

  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
      self.counter = K.variable(0, name='counter',dtype='int32')
      self.lr_cand = K.variable(self.lr, name='lr_cand')
      self.lastloss= K.variable(1e9,   name='lastloss')
      self.dloss   = K.variable([1,0,0],   name='dloss')
      self.lr_update_facs = K.constant([1.0, 1.3, 1.0/1.3])

  @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
  def get_updates(self, loss, params):

    dloss_update = K.update( self.dloss[ (self.counter+2) % 3 ] , self.dloss[ (self.counter+2) % 3 ] + (self.lastloss - loss) )

    lastloss_save = K.update( self.lastloss, loss )

    update_lr  =  K.update(self.lr_cand, K.switch( self.counter % 18, self.lr_cand, self.lr_cand * K.gather(self.lr_update_facs, K.argmax(self.dloss) ) ) )
    reset_hist =  K.update(self.dloss,   K.switch( self.counter % 18, self.dloss, K.constant( [0.0,0.0,0.0]) ) )

    lr_upd = K.update(self.lr, self.lr_cand * K.gather( self.lr_update_facs, self.counter % 3 ) )
    super_updates = super().get_updates(loss,params)
    counter_update = K.update(self.counter,self.counter+1 )

    updates = [dloss_update, lastloss_save, update_lr, reset_hist, lr_upd, super_updates, counter_update]

    return updates

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))

opt = AutoOptim()
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])


class My_Callback(callbacks.Callback):
  def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    print(K.eval(self.model.optimizer.counter)-1, K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr), K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lastloss), K.eval(self.model.optimizer.dloss))


#%%
X=np.random.rand(500,2)
Y=(X[:,0]+X[:,1])/2

model.fit(X,Y,epochs=1, callbacks=[My_Callback()], batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

I expect to see a learning rate cycling through the 3 values (current, slightly higher, slightly lower) and set a new 'current' value every 18 epochs.

I get rather erratic behaviour, with dloss and lr not updating as expected.

Comment: The get_updates method isn't invoked because there is an indentation issue resulting in get_updates becoming part of __init__.  So, Nadam's get_updates gets invoked and not AutoOptim's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code formatting issue:

The get_updates method isn't invoked because there is an indentation issue resulting in get_updates() becoming part of __init__().  So, Nadam's get_updates() gets invoked.

Once indentation issue was fixed, AutoOptim's get_updates() got invoked.

You can print the values of variables like this in the get_updates() method:

```
print(f'Learning rate: {K.get_session().run([self.lr,self.lr_cand])}')
```

Comment: Fixed the bugs that appeared when the function was called, but still puzzled about the print issue.

Comment: Updated answer on print.